# Video file won't play using jwplayer

Tags: javascript, video, m3u8

I'm not a professional, I'm doing a blind imitation
I created and memorized the m3u8 file
This is what it contains

```html
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXTINF:3.000,
lo-1.ts
#EXTINF:3.000,
lo-2.ts
```

However, when I uploaded it to the storage puller and created the link to run it on the web, it didn't work
What should I add and how, for the video to work

[This is my link](https://okoshiyasu.000webhostapp.com/lo.m3u8)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtk5hjfd/)

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/0P4vdmeO.js'></script>
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      file: "https://okoshiyasu.000webhostapp.com/lo.m3u8",
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://okoshiyasu.000webhostapp.com/lo.m3u8. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`.

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is in the cloud storage

Comment: No, it means you haven't set the right CORS headers.

Comment: I searched for what you mean by CORS and found that it has something to do with the domain name of the primary and secondary file
But how can I solve the problem

Comment: uploaded the ts file to the same domain and I modified the file like

#EXTINF:3.000,
lo-1.ts
#EXTINF:3.000,
lo-2.ts

 But the problem remains

Comment: you must configure the http server to send the correct CORS headers. How you do that depends on what server/service you are using.

Comment: So tell me... **(1)** Can you run PHP on your server? If yes, I might have idea to avoid CORS problem. **(2)** You have shown link for `.ts` file but also the `.html` and `.ts` files must be added at `https://okoshiyasu.000webhostapp.com/`. **(3)** Make sure the `.ts` bytes is downloaded, not printed (displayed) as text in a tab... IF still not working, then my last idea is to put your player `.html` file and the `.ts` files in a different host like Github. Then use I-Frame to still watch via `okoshiyasu` link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I uploaded the `.ts` file to the same domain and I modified the file like `#EXTINF:3.000, lo-1.ts`
> But the problem remains"*

There is something wrong with your file host (maybe in  settings?). Instead of giving raw file bytes, it instead gives a *text* version of the file bytes.

For example, when using Chrome, try to open these links in a **new tab**:

1) Your host: https://okoshiyasu.000webhostapp.com/lo-1.ts **=** shows text in tab (**wrong** result).

2) Github test: https://vcone.github.io/public/demos/Mpeg_TS/lo-1.ts **=** downloads file (**correct** result).

Becase the file bytes are downloaded (not written text on page) this mean the HLS player gets the data correctly and can now play the video.

Example playback (where `.ts` file is served from Github):
https://vcone.github.io/public/demos/Mpeg_TS/VC1_Demo_LO_01.html

**Solution:**
Find a way to fix these links of your `.ts` file(s) to auto-download to disk. When that is fixed, then the file is also now playable by HLS players. Maybe you can set file **type** settings if possible? Right now it acts like you uploaded a web page (or text) instead of binary data (file bytes). Maybe it is not allowed for their free space? Check with `000webhostapp.com` Admins or forums.